# Error: File to import not found or unreadable: node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gulp, laravel-elixir

I get the following error when installing elixir on laravel 5.2.31

> ```
>    gulp
> [12:05:58] Using gulpfile /var/www/html/ta/gulpfile.js
> [12:05:58] Starting 'default'...
> [12:05:58] Starting 'sass'...
>
> Fetching Sass Source Files...
>    - resources/assets/sass/app.scss
>
>
> Saving To...
>    - public/css/app.css
>
> [12:06:01] Finished 'default' after 2.17 s
> [12:06:01] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Sass Compilation Failed: resources/assets/sass/app.scss
> Error: File to import not found or unreadable: node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap
>        Parent style sheet: /var/www/html/ta/resources/assets/sass/app.scss
>         on line 1 of resources/assets/sass/app.scss
> >> @import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
>    ^
>
> { Error: resources/assets/sass/app.scss
> Error: File to import not found or unreadable: node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap
>        Parent style sheet: /var/www/html/ta/resources/assets/sass/app.scss
>         on line 1 of resources/assets/sass/app.scss
> >> @import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
>    ^
>
>     at options.error (/var/www/html/ta/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:286:26)
>   status: 1,
>   file: '/var/www/html/ta/resources/assets/sass/app.scss',
>   line: 1,
>   column: 1,
>   message: 'resources/assets/sass/app.scss\nError: File to import not found or unreadable:
> ```
>
> node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap\n
>   Parent style sheet: /var/www/html/ta/resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n 
>   on line 1 of resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n>> @import
>   "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";\n   ^\n',
>         formatted: 'Error: File to import not found or unreadable: node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap\n
>   Parent style sheet: /var/www/html/ta/resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n 
>   on line 1 of resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n>> @import
>   "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";\n   ^\n',
>         messageFormatted: '\u001b[4mresources/assets/sass/app.scss\u001b[24m\nError: File to
>   import not found or unreadable:
>   node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap\n
>   Parent style sheet: /var/www/html/ta/resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n 
>   on line 1 of resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n>> @import
>   "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";\n   ^\n',
>         messageOriginal: 'File to import not found or unreadable: node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap\nParent style
>   sheet: /var/www/html/ta/resources/assets/sass/app.scss',
>         relativePath: 'resources/assets/sass/app.scss',
>         name: 'Error',
>         stack: 'Error: resources/assets/sass/app.scss\nError: File to import not found or unreadable:
>   node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap\n
>   Parent style sheet: /var/www/html/ta/resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n 
>   on line 1 of resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n>> @import
>   "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";\n   ^\n\n 
>   at options.error
>   (/var/www/html/ta/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:286:26)',
>         showStack: false,
>         showProperties: true,
>         plugin: 'gulp-sass' }
>       [12:06:01] Finished 'sass' after 2.24 s

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error with Laravel Mix (the service replacing Elixir):

`File to import not found or unreadable: node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap`

I realized this was because I forgot to run `npm install` from within my project directory. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: ok thank you sir, this work for me. and i change "laravel-elixir": "*", in package.json

Answer (score 0):

I had also a similar problem while running gulp on my angularjs project. I already run npm install but the problem was still there.

```
File to import not found or unreadable
```

I fixed it by running npm update.